# camel spring boot kubernetes cluster Leader does not update renew time and changed old leader

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, kubernetes-cluster, leader-election

I have built a camel spring boot kubernetes cluster. (spring boot 3, camel-kubernetes 4)

however, clustering is not completed. this pod stream-server-5b56d9599-n4jxf was already deleted. New pods could not take a leader forcely.

```
    KubernetesLeadershipController - L:180 Pod\[stream-server-5b56d9599-n4jxf\] Leadership has been lost by old owner. Trying to acquire the leadership...
```

```
    kubectl get leases --watch
    NAME            HOLDER                           AGE
    leaders-lock2   stream-server-7f9794664d-rfxrp   21h
```

How am i do to solve this problem ?

If you need to any information to solve this problem, please let me know freely.

if clustering is properly created, this log will be printed

```
    MasterConsumer - L:155 Leadership taken. Consumer started: timer://clustered?period=10000"
    [Camel (camel-1) thread #6 - timer://clustered] INFO  clustered - L:166 Clustered route (timer) ...
```

Comment: Application components was changed from spring boot 3 with camel-kubernetes 4.x to spring boot 2.7.x with camel-kubernetes 3.10.x and Clustering is properly worked.

Comment: please let me know properly maven configuration spring-boot 3 with camel-kubernetes 4

Comment: correction from 3.10.x to 3.20.x